# Android 2.3 ListView setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to make my app compatible to 2.3 and I'm stuck trying to make the setOnItemClickListener work. It works perfectly on 4.0 but it doesn't on 2.3. I've been researching and found I have to make  android:focusable="false" android:clickable="false" my item in the XML but it still doesn't work. This is my code:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_menu"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:padding="@dimen/lateral_menu_items_separator_height"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_4" />

    <com.grability.eci.views.widgets.BasicTextViewRegular
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size_item_menu" />

</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA:

list_menu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.e("onItemClick ", "Clicked");
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: remove `android:focusable="false"` and `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` and `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Comment: No, still doesn't work. But thanks.

Comment: Ok, I think `com.grability.eci.views.widgets.BasicTextViewRegular` makes that problem. just comment it and your listview item click must work, if it dose now go to next step to add `android:focusable="false"` just for `BasicTextViewRegular` if it dose not I think you must check your code by a tutorial on the net because your list is very simple in this case.

Comment: just to make my last comment clear: after removing `<com.grability.eci.views.widgets.BasicTextViewRegular` your `listview` must work.

Comment: I changed it from <com.grability.eci.views.widgets.BasicTextViewRegular to a regular TextView and still doesn't work. Do you mean to remove the whole TextView ?

Answer (score 0):

have you modify your manifest file

set the minsdkversion to the current api, which is gonna be android:minSdkVersion="9" and try again..
Best Regards

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Yes, I have minSdkVersion="9" but still doesn't work :s

Comment: That's the thing I don't get any error log, not even this log -> Log.e("onItemClick ", "Clicked");

Comment: Kindly, Rebuild your project or probably restart the ide and check again.but i think you should add listView inside the XML layout.

Comment: Hi, no it still doesn't work. The layout I posted is the item layout of the lists.